# HBO GO doesn't work

Tags: video, flash, video-player, drm

Does anybody know how to get hbo go to work on ubuntu?

I have installed hal.  Tried it with and without pepperflash.

Deleted the flash player folder.  None of that works.

Comment: any luck with this.  Can't find a solution that has worked for me either.

Comment: I still haven't found a DRM solution, since support was pulled for Flash.  I don't think Linux Chrome-bundled flash has HAL support though

Comment: does piplight now have flash in it - I think that might be the only way now is to use the windows version somehow

Comment: @Mateo not sure, though I doubt it will work without a lot of work.  I also know that HBONOW and Hulu both require HAL + Flash 17 or newer so... :/

Comment: Following Christopher's answer:  I still couldn't watch on chromium. But it will play on Firefox (I'm not sure whether it would have previously because I hadn't tried).

Answer (score 2):

The flash player needs hal to handle the drm.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mjblenner/ppa-hal
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hal
```

More info here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/10/fixing-amazon-prime-streaming-drm-protected-flash-13-10?utm_source=feedly

This worked for me on Linux Mint 16 (Ubuntu 13.10) and Linux mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Mint is NOT Ubuntu